# Holding session option in Fortiweb

Tags: firewall, security, fortinet, proxy, http-proxy

I have Frotiweb installed as my WAF and it is connected to FrotiSandbox for behavioral detection.  In the WAF' File Security Policy,  I have the "Hold Session While Scanning" turned off and "Send File to FortiSandbox" turned on.  Does that mean uploaded files to web apps will be delivered to the web servers, while FortiSandbox has not yet finished its inspection?

In the Fortweb admin guide, it says that turning on "Hopd Session While Scanning" will make WAF waits for FortiSandbox result to come back up to 30 mins. But, it does not say what happens when it is turned off.

Appreciate all the help I can get

Comment: Please do not post text as a picture. Also, you need to include sufficient details in your question for us to understand the problem.

Comment: Sorry for that.  I have updated it.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Does that mean uploaded files to web apps will be delivered to the web servers, while FortiSandbox has not yet finished its inspection?

Yes, that is what it means. You can either wait for FortiSandbox inspection to finish or you don't.